# How to implement change prefix command with cogs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

First of all, this is my bot directories.

[image]

now, this is how all the events and command to facilitate prefix change looks like.

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot ready hai')

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = "!" # default value, implemented when bot joins for the first time

    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

---

command

```
@client.command()
async def changeprefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = new_prefix

    with open("./prefixes_data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    ctx.send(f"Changed the prefix to: {new_prefix}")
```

now, i want to do this, but using cogs(specifically, the bot moderation cog). But i am not getting desired thing. Please Help. Please. this is the cog code i tried.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

class botmodcoms(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command
    async def changeprefix(self, ctx, new_prefix):
        with open("../prefixes_data.json", "r") as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = new_prefix
        
        with open("../prefixes_data.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(botmodcoms(client))
```

what i want is all the events should be in the main bot.py file, and the command come under the cog file (BotModeration)

Comment: When saying "this does not work in Cogs", it helps to post the code that you tried so we can identify the problem. Can you show the Cog's code & what you tried to do?

Comment: @stijndcl sure, wait a second

Comment: Are you loading the cog in your main bot.py file? I don't see you doing that anywhere. Could be a stupid question but it could also be the answer.

Comment: @stijndcl yes I have loaded the cog in the main bot.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I have seemed to make it work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

class Config(commands.Cog, name="Configuration"):
        
        def __init__(self, bot):
            self.bot = bot
            
        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} Cog has been loaded\n-----")
            
        @commands.command()
        async def prefix(self, ctx, new_prefix):
                  with open("./prefixes.json", "r") as f:
                    prefixes = json.load(f)
                    
                    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = new_prefix
                    
                    with open("./prefixes.json", "w") as f:
                        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
            
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Config(bot))
```